# How to ignore part of the text or a complete html tag on datatable sorting

Tags: javascript, datatable

My datatable has two columns that contains created date and modified date. When only the date is in the table row, the sorting works perfectly.

But I need to add the name of the person who performed the task underneath the date. When I add the date the sorting is not correct according to the date. I think it is because the name also getting included in the sorting.

This is how I render the column.

```
{
   title: "Modified Date",
   data: "updated-date",
   render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
          var html = full.updatedDate;

          if (full.updatedBy.id) {
              html += "<br/><small>" + full.updatedBy.name + "</small>";
          }
          return html;
   }
}
```

And this is how the columns are displayed when sorted at the moment.
[image]

Is there a class or a special html tag that I can use to make the sorting ignore the names?

Comment: Would you give me detail about your database and sort function?

Comment: Data is rendered in the frontend using a JSON object and do not have a sort function. It is sorted using datatables default sorting.

Comment: So within `render`, correct me if I am wrong, but it appears that you are just adding the that html as a string to the `.html` attribute. You could actually just create the outer element and set its `innerHTML` to be the remainder, then use javascripts `.getElementsBy___` or `querySelector()` methods to select the specific element and then just `remove()` it.

Comment: @Shmack - yes but I do not want to remove the name. I want the datatable to only consider the date when sorting. The name should be displayed under the date all the time.

Comment: Sorry, its late and I misread / misunderstood the question - maybe you could store the name in a `data-name` attribute for each element, load the table with just the date, then append the name after each element is loaded? It just might be annoying detecting the event.

Comment: In your `render` function, the parameters are `data`, `type`, `full`, and `meta`. Use the `type` parameter to control what data is used in the display vs. what data is used for sorting (and filtering). See [Orthogonal Data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data#API-interface) for the official documentation. There are also lots of questions on Stack Overflow already with [more examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=datatables+orthogonal+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@andrewJames](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12567365/andrewjames) comment I was able to fix this using the `type` parameter passed into the `render()` function.

`type` parameter can be used to determine between the data that needs to be sorted and displayed.

```
{
   title: "Modified Date",
   data: "updated-date",
   render: function (data, type, full, meta) {

      if (type === "sort" || type === 'type') {
           return full.updatedDate; // return only date for sorting and ordering
      }
      else {
           // display the date with html tags
           var html = full.updatedDate;

           if (full.updatedBy.id) {
               html += "<br/><small>" + full.updatedBy.name + "</small>";
           }
           return html;
       }

    }
 }
```

Comment: That's it, yes. But I think `type === 'type'` should be `type === 'filter'` (and the comment should be "for sorting and filtering").